# React-Native - How is it possible that when I close an app like messenger I can still receive incoming call notifications

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

React-Native - How is it possible that when I close an app like messenger I can still receive incoming call notifications from others

I'm using react-native-notifee and react-native-firebase-messaging

channel code

`await notifee.createChannel({ id: 'custom_sound_2', name: 'sound_2', importance: AndroidImportance.HIGH, visibility: AndroidVisibility.PUBLIC, sound: 'ridetune', vibration: true, });`

messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
});